# code.interact() doesn't understand arrow keys when stdin is set to a socket

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sockets

I'm making a lightweight manhole-like remote interactive Python shell by setting `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` to a socket and then calling `code.interact()`.

This works beautifully except for arrow keys showing up like `^[[C` when I connect to it via `nc localhost 1337`.

It's not an issue of not having `readline` installed, as that works fine when I launch the interpreter manually, even if I run `code.interact()`. The issue only occurs through sockets. I can `import readline` inside my remote shell but that does nothing.

Perhaps I'm missing something related to `readline` in `SocketWrapper.read()`?

```
import socket
import sys
import readline
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete') # doesn't work
import code

port = 1337

while True:
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('', port))
    sock.listen(1)
    print("~Listening on port %d~" % port)
    connection, connection_addr = sock.accept()
    print("Accepted connection from %s." % (connection_addr,))

    class SocketWrapper:
        def __init__(self, sock):
            self.sock = sock

        def read(self, length):
            return self.sock.recv(length)

        def write(self, text):
            return self.sock.send(text)

        def readline(self):
            return self.sock.makefile().readline()

    sockfile = SocketWrapper(connection)

    sys.stdin = sockfile
    sys.stdout = sockfile
    sys.stderr = sockfile

    code.interact(
        local=dict(globals(), **locals())
    )
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure line completion has to happen on the *other* side of the socket.

Comment: @user2357112 Hmm why is that? Does that mean that it's impossible to do line editing if the client is merely a netcat instance? If I can use backspace, I don't see why arrow keys are any less feasible.

Comment: Backspace is handled on the other side of the socket.

Comment: Hmmm but perhaps I could pull some shenanigans with carriage returns to simply rewrite the current line with e.g. the previous input when <up> is pressed. Integrating that with the Python interpreter is the part I'm lost on though.

Comment: Python has no idea that the up arrow key was pressed. That's all happening on the other side of the socket.

Comment: Ahhhh I see now. However, if I run ` stty -icanon && nc [...]` as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/429134/197038), sys.stdout.read(1) returns on the first character (even if I press up arrow), and pressing backspace sends `^?`.

Comment: With that, you could probably make Python perform line completion over the socket, but I don't think the `readline` module will do that for you. I'm pretty sure the underlying C library is hooked up to the C-level stdin and stdout, without any option exposed for Python code to change that.